# How to template calls involving member functions and derived classes

Tags: c++, templates

I have a state machine sort of thing encapsulated in a class. This is done by calling a sequence of member functions in turn to do the actions. I also have several derived classes, and I want to do the same sequence on them. Is there a way I can template this code?

```
#include <iostream>

class MyClass {
    std::string name;
public:
    typedef void (MyClass::*Function)(std::ostream &ostr);
    void Func1(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F1" << name << std::endl; };
    void Func2(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F2" << std::endl; };
    static Function printers[];
    void Print(std::ostream &ostr);
};

MyClass::Function MyClass::printers[] = {
    &MyClass::Func1,
    &MyClass::Func2,
    NULL
};

void MyClass::Print(std::ostream &ostr)
{
    // various stuff to do before
    // ...
    int i = 0;
    for (Function *fp = printers; *fp; fp++, i++) {
        std::cerr << "Calling function " << i << std::endl;
        ((this)->*(*fp))(ostr);
        std::cerr << "Called function " << i << std::endl;
    }
    // other stuff here...
}

class DerClass: public MyClass {
    int index;
public:
    typedef void (DerClass::*Function)(std::ostream &ostr);
    void Func3(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F3" << index << std::endl; };
    static Function printers[];
    void Print(std::ostream &ostr);
};

DerClass::Function DerClass::printers[] = {
    &DerClass::Func1,
    &DerClass::Func3,
    NULL
};

// I'd rather not repeat all this stuff, can I template it??
void DerClass::Print(std::ostream &ostr)
{
    // various stuff to do before
    // ...
    int i = 0;
    for (Function *fp = printers; *fp; fp++, i++) {
        std::cerr << "Calling function " << i << std::endl;
        ((this)->*(*fp))(ostr);
        std::cerr << "Called function " << i << std::endl;
    }
    // other stuff here...
}

int main()
{
    MyClass cl1;
    cl1.Print(std::cout);
    DerClass cl2;
    cl2.Print(std::cout);
}
```

The code runs, and works, but I'd like to write the Print routine just once, rather than for each new class, is there a way to do that, templates? Other classes?

I was hoping for something like

```
template <class T>
void T::Print(std::ostream &str) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Function *fp = printers; *fp; fp++, i++) {
    std::cerr << "Calling function " << i << std::endl;
    ((this)->*(*fp))(ostr);
    std::cerr << "Called function " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

That doesn't compile though.

> error: invalid use of template type parameter ‘T’  void
>   T::Print(std::ostream &str) {

Comment: Templates for which types actually? Did you mean CRTP?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a template, but some way of writing the Print routine just once.

Comment: The difference between `MyClass::Print` and `DerClass::Print` is in the omitted code ? May virtual `PrePrint`, `PostPrint` help ?

Comment: That would help there, but I still have to write a new Print function every time I derive a class. I was hoping for something like

   template <class T>
void T::Print(std::ostream &str) {
    int i = 0;
    for (Function *fp = printers; *fp; fp++, i++) {
 std::cerr << "Calling function " << i << std::endl;
 ((this)->*(*fp))(ostr);
 std::cerr << "Called function " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
but that doesn't compile.
 error: invalid use of template type parameter ‘T’
 void T::Print(std::ostream &str) {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rather write this as a comment, but the amount of code wouldn't be readable at all.

Below you can find a possible solution on how to "inherit" your `Print`.

This should only be taken as suggestion or hint. Especially the initialization of the `printers` is not really done in "a good way".

Hope it helps you nonetheless

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


template <class Derived>
class MyClass {

    std::string name;

protected:
    typedef void (Derived::*Function)(std::ostream &ostr);
    Function* printers;

public:
    MyClass() 
        :printers(nullptr)
    {
    }

    ~MyClass()
    {
        delete[] printers;
    }

    virtual void initPrinters()
    {
        if (printers == nullptr)
        {
            printers = new Function[3];
            printers[0] = &MyClass<Derived>::Func1;
            printers[1] = &MyClass<Derived>::Func2;
            printers[2] = NULL;
        }
    }

    void destroyPrinters()
    {
        if (printers != nullptr)
        {
            delete[] printers;
        }
    }

    void Print(std::ostream &ostr)
    {
        initPrinters();
        // various stuff to do before
        // ...
        int i = 0;
        for (Function *fp = printers; *fp; fp++, i++) {
            std::cerr << "Calling function " << i << std::endl;
            (((Derived*)this)->*(*fp))(ostr);
            std::cerr << "Called function " << i << std::endl;
        }
        // other stuff here...
    }

    void Func1(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F1" << name << std::endl; };
    void Func2(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F2" << std::endl; };
};

template <>
class MyClass<void> : public MyClass<MyClass<void>>
{
};

class DerClass : public MyClass<DerClass> {
    int index;

public:

    virtual void initPrinters() override
    {
        if (printers == nullptr)
        {
            printers = new Function[3];
            printers[0] = &DerClass::Func1;
            printers[1] = &DerClass::Func3;
            printers[2] = NULL;
        }
    }

    void Func3(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F3" << index << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    MyClass<void> cl1;
    cl1.Print(std::cout);
    DerClass cl2;
    cl2.Print(std::cout);
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Second Approach

This one is prettier in my opinion. Also it is less code and it can be optimized by the compiler:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


class MyClass {

    std::string name;

protected:


    template <class T>
    void print(std::ostream &ostr, void(T::*printFunc)(std::ostream&))
    {
        (((T*)this)->*printFunc)(ostr);
    }

    template <class T, typename... PrintFunctions>
    void print(std::ostream &ostr, void(T::*printFunc)(std::ostream&), PrintFunctions... printFuncs)
    {
        (((T*)this)->*printFunc)(ostr);
        print(ostr, printFuncs...);
    }

public:

    virtual void Print(std::ostream &ostr)
    {
        print(ostr, &MyClass::Func1, &MyClass::Func2);
    }

    void Func1(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F1" << name << std::endl; };
    void Func2(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F2" << std::endl; };
};

class DerClass : public MyClass {
    int index;

public:
    virtual void Print(std::ostream &ostr) override
    {
        print(ostr, &DerClass::Func1, &DerClass::Func3);
    }

    void Func3(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F3" << index << std::endl; };
};

int main()
{
    MyClass cl1;
    cl1.Print(std::cout);
    DerClass cl2;
    cl2.Print(std::cout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - thats very helpful, gives be a place to experiment from!

Comment: Updated with a more template based approach

Comment: That is nice - thanks a lot. I'd like to use an array of functions though, as sometimes I have 20 or more to call.

Comment: You do realize that there is no limit in the function to pass to `print`?
You could easily change `DerClass::Print` to call e.g.: `print(ostr, &DerClass::Func1, &DerClass::Func2, &DerClass::Func3, &DerClass::Func1, &DerClass::Func2, &DerClass::Func3, &DerClass::Func1, &DerClass::Func2, &DerClass::Func3);`

Answer (score 0):

If "various stuff" and "other stuff" are different, you can make those parts virtual.

But you can't call a member function of a subclass in the base class, the functions all need to have the same type.

One suggestion might be to indirect through free functions.

```
class MyClass;
typedef void (*Printer)(MyClass*, std::ostream&);

class MyClass {
    std::string name;
public:
    MyClass();
    void Func1(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F1" << name << std::endl; };
    void Func2(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F2" << std::endl; };
    void Print(std::ostream &ostr);
protected:
    MyClass(Printer* ps) : myprinters(ps) {}
    virtual void PrePrint() { /* Various stuff... */ }
    virtual void PostPrint() { /* Other stuff... */ }
private:
    Printer* myprinters;

};

void MyFunc1(MyClass* obj, std::ostream& os) { obj->Func1(os); }
void MyFunc2(MyClass* obj, std::ostream& os) { obj->Func2(os); }

Printer myclassprinters[] = {
    &MyFunc1,
    &MyFunc2,
    NULL
};

MyClass::MyClass()
    : myprinters(myclassprinters)
{

}

void MyClass::Print(std::ostream &ostr)
{
    PrePrint();
    int i = 0;
    for (Printer *fp = myprinters; *fp; fp++, i++) {
        std::cerr << "Calling function " << i << std::endl;
        (*fp)(this, ostr);
        std::cerr << "Called function " << i << std::endl;
    }
    PostPrint();
}

class DerClass: public MyClass {
public:
    DerClass();
    void Func3(std::ostream &ostr) { ostr << "F3" << index << std::endl; };
protected:
    void PrePrint() { /* More stuff... */ }
};

// C-cast for conciseness only. Use something safer in the real world.
void DerFunc(MyClass* obj, std::ostream& ostr) { ((DerClass*)obj)->Func3(ostr); }

Printer derclassprinters[] = {
    &MyFunc1,
    &DerFunc,
    NULL
};

DerClass::DerClass()
    : MyClass(derclassprinters)
{

}
```

This uses a pointer member for each instance - I'm assuming you don't want to store the entire function table for every instance.

Comment: Thanks - I did wonder about doing it this way, but while it works, you have to write a lot of encapsulating functions.